# Check proof that $p^i(1-p)^{n-i }\gt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$ for every $p\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, $n\in\mathbb N$ and $i\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, exponential-function

I’d like to ask wether my proof of the following proposition is correct. Thanks..

---

**Proposition:**

**(Prop.1):**

$\forall p\in (0,\frac{1}{2}),\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }\gt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$

**(Prop.2):**

$\forall p\in \{\frac{1}{2}\},\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }= p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$

**(Prop.3):** 
$\forall p\in (\frac{1}{2},1),\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }\lt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$

---

**Proof:**

**(Prop.1):**

Let $p\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, We’ll prove that $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$:

Since $n\in\mathbb{N}$, We have $1\leq n$, And thus $0\leq n-1$, And we conclude that $0\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, And thus we’ll prove it first for the case $i=0\in\{0,...,n-1\}$:

For $i=0$ we have:

**(Eq.1)** $p^i(1-p)^{n-i }=p^0(1-p)^{n-0}=(1-p)^n$

And:

**(Eq.2)** $p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}=p^{0+1}(1-p)^{n-(0+1)}=p(1-p)^{n-1}$

Now since $p\lt \frac{1}{2}$, We get that $2p\lt 1$, And so **(Ineq.1)** $p\lt 1-p$, But since $0<p$, We get by **(Ineq.1)** that it is also the case that $0\lt 1-p$, And thus $0\lt (1-p)^{n-1}$ (because the exponential function is always positive),

Now by multiplying **(Ineq.1)** by $(1-p)^{n-1}>0$, We conclude that $p(1-p)^{n-1}\lt (1-p)(1-p)^{n-1}=(1-p)^n$, But this implies by **(Eq.1)** and **(Eq.2)** that $p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i }\gt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$ as was to be shown.

Now since $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we get that there are two cases **(case 1)** $n=1$ or **(case 2)** $2\leq n$:

**(case 1):** If $n=1$, Then we get $n-1=0$, And thus $\{0,...,n-1\}=\{0\}$,

But since we’ve already shown that for $i=0$, We have $p^{i}(1-p)^{n-i }\gt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$, We conclude that $\forall i\in\{0\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$, And thus $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$.

**(case 2):** If $2\leq n$, Then we have $0\leq n-2$, And thus $0\in\{0,...,n-2\}$.

Now we’ll prove by ***terminating induction*** on $i$ that $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$:

(**Note:** We use ***terminating induction*** since $i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$ and thus we have to terminate the induction at some point)

**(base case):**
For $i=0\in\{0,...,n-2\}$, We have to show that $p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$, But this is exactly what we’ve already shown at the beginning.

**(inductive step):**
Now suppose that for some $i=k\in\{0,...,n-2\}$ we have $p^k(1-p)^{n-k }>p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k +1)}$, And we’ll prove that for $i=k+1\in\{1,...,n-1\}$ we have $p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k+1) }>p^{k+2}(1-p)^{n-(k +2)}$:

(**Note:** Note that we ensure in the inductive step that both $k$ and $k+1$ are within $\{0,...,n-1\}$ and do not get out of the bounds)

Since $0\lt p$ and since we’ve already shown that $0\lt 1-p$, We have $0\lt \frac{p}{1-p}$, Now since by the induction hypothesis we have $p^k(1-p)^{n-k }\gt p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k +1)}$, We get by multiplying this inequality by $\frac{p}{1-p}\gt 0$ that:

$p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k+1)}=\frac{p}{1-p}p^k(1-p)^{n-k }\gt \frac{p}{1-p}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-(k +1)}=p^{k+2}(1-p)^{n-(k +2)}$ as was to be shown.

Thus we see from cases **(case 1)** and **(case 2)** that it is always the case that  $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }>p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$ as was to be shown.

Q.E.D.

**(Prop.2):**

Let $p\in \{\frac{1}{2}\}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $ i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, We’ll prove that $p^i(1-p)^{n-i }=p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$:

Since $p\in\{\frac{1}{2}\}$, We get that $p=\frac{1}{2}$, And thus $1-p=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}=p$, But this implies that $p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}=p^i\cdot p\cdot(1-p)^{n-i-1}=p^i\cdot (1-p)\cdot (1-p)^{n-i-1}=p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$

as was to be shown.

Q.E.D.

**(Prop.3):**

Let $p\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, We’ll prove that $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }<p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$:

Since $\frac{1}{2}<p<1$, We get that $-1<-p<-\frac{1}{2}$, And this implies that $0=1-1<1-p<1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$, And thus $1-p\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, Now let’s define $q:=1-p$, And we get that $1-q=1-(1-p)=1-1+p=p$ and that $q\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$, And thus by **(Prop.1)** we conclude that **(Fact.1)** $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, q^i(1-q)^{n-i }\gt q^{i+1}(1-q)^{n-(i +1)}$,

Now we’ll prove that **(Fact.2)** $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i }\gt p^{n-(i+1)}(1-p)^{i+1}$:

Let $i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, Then by **(Fact.1)** we get that $q^i(1-q)^{n-i }\gt q^{i+1}(1-q)^{n-(i +1)}$, But since $q^i(1-q)^{n-i }=(1-p)^i p^{n-i}=p^{n-i}(1-p)^i$ and since $q^{i+1}(1-q)^{n-(i +1)}=(1-p)^{i+1}p^{n-(i +1)}=p^{n-(i+1)}(1-p)^{i+1}$, We conclude that $p^{n-i}(1-p)^{i }\gt p^{n-(i+1)}(1-p)^{i+1}$ as was to be shown.

Now we’ll finnish the proof by showing that $\forall i\in\{0,...,n-1\}, p^i(1-p)^{n-i }<p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$:

Let $i\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, Then $0\leq i\leq n-1$, And thus $-n+1\leq -i\leq 0$, Which implies that $1=n-n+1\leq n-i\leq n$, And thus $0=1-1\leq n-i-1\leq n-1$, But this implies that $n-i-1\in\{0,...,n-1\}$, And thus we can conclude by **(Fact.2)**, That $p^{n-(n-i-1)}(1-p)^{n-i-1 }\gt p^{n-(n-i -1+1)}(1-p)^{n-i -1+1}$, But since $p^{n-(n-i-1)}(1-p)^{n-i-1 }=p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$ and since $p^{n-(n-i -1+1)}(1-p)^{n-i -1+1}=p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$, We conclude that $p^i(1-p)^{n-i}\lt p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}$ as was to be shown.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Rather than using induction, it is more straightforward to write $p^{i+1}(1-p)^{n-(i +1)}=[p^i(1-p)^{n-i }]\times\frac{p}{1-p}$, and study when the fraction $ \frac{p}{1-p}$ is lower or greater than $1$.

Comment: @Suzet thanks for the tip, I will try to prove it in your way too.